# Hibernate not creating table postgreSQL

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, maven, wildfly

With 2 other students, we are working on a classic JEE project : 
 - We use Spring + Hibernate + Maven
 - PostgreSQL database (Code first)
 - WildFly 10.x

We did a test to insert a table in the database, following a tutorial

Our problem is that Hibernate is not creating the table in the database (`ERROR: relation "phone" does not exist`). Mainly, this problem can occurs for 2 reasons : Incorrect JDBC or lacks of privileges for the database user.
So, we checked the first one and granted all privileges to our user on database/schema.
We figured out hibernate was generating our select queries (`Hibernate: select phone0_.id as id1_0_, phone0_.name as name2_0_, phone0_.review as review3_0_ from PHONE phone0_`), but not the create table query.

Console output ("ERREUR: la relation « phone » n'existe pas" means "ERROR : Relation "phone" does not exists"):

```
15:01:50,099 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "PostgresDS")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.SOVECO-0_0_1-SNAPSHOT_war_org_postgresql_Driver_9_4"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:/PostgresDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.SOVECO-0_0_1-SNAPSHOT_war_org_postgresql_Driver_9_4]",
        "org.wildfly.data-source.PostgresDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.SOVECO-0_0_1-SNAPSHOT_war_org_postgresql_Driver_9_4]"
    ]
}
15:01:50,105 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "PostgresDS")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.SOVECO-0_0_1-SNAPSHOT_war_org_postgresql_Driver_9_4",
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.SOVECO-0_0_1-SNAPSHOT_war_org_postgresql_Driver_9_4"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:/PostgresDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.SOVECO-0_0_1-SNAPSHOT_war_org_postgresql_Driver_9_4]",
        "org.wildfly.data-source.PostgresDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.SOVECO-0_0_1-SNAPSHOT_war_org_postgresql_Driver_9_4]",
        "org.wildfly.data-source.PostgresDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.SOVECO-0_0_1-SNAPSHOT_war_org_postgresql_Driver_9_4]"
    ]
}
15:01:50,207 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.SOVECO-0_0_1-SNAPSHOT_war_org_postgresql_Driver_9_4 (missing) dependents: [service jboss.driver-demander.java:/PostgresDS, service org.wildfly.data-source.PostgresDS] 

15:01:50,388 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started (with errors) in 7071ms - Started 332 of 583 services (4 services failed or missing dependencies, 394 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)

WFLYCTL0185:    Newly corrected services:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.SOVECO-0_0_1-SNAPSHOT_war_org_postgresql_Driver_9_4 (new available)
15:02:42,941 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) Hibernate: select phone0_.id as id1_0_, phone0_.name as name2_0_, phone0_.review as review3_0_ from PHONE phone0_
15:02:42,949 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-5) ERREUR: la relation « phone » n'existe pas
  Position : 90
15:02:42,957 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-5) UT005023: Exception handling request to /SOVECO/phones: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
...
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: la relation « phone » n'existe pas
  Position : 90
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:168)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:71)
    ... 93 more
15:08:23,927 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Hibernate: select phone0_.id as id1_0_, phone0_.name as name2_0_, phone0_.review as review3_0_ from PHONE phone0_

15:08:23,929 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-6) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
15:08:23,929 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-6) ERREUR: la relation « phone » n'existe pas
  Position : 90
15:08:23,931 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-6) UT005023: Exception handling request to /SOVECO/phones: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
...
15:08:41,752 INFO  [stdout] (default task-7) Hibernate: select phone0_.id as id1_0_, phone0_.name as name2_0_, phone0_.review as review3_0_ from PHONE phone0_
15:08:41,756 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-7) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
15:08:41,756 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-7) ERREUR: la relation « phone » n'existe pas
  Position : 90
15:08:41,757 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-7) UT005023: Exception handling request to /SOVECO/phones: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: la relation « phone » n'existe pas
```

PhoneDAO :

```
import java.util.List;
import fr.spring.demo.model.Phone;

public interface PhoneDAO {
    public void addPhone(Phone p);

    public void updatePhone(Phone p);

    public List<Phone> listPhones();

    public Phone getPhoneById(int id);

    public void removePhone(int id);
}
```

Class PhoneDAOImpl :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import fr.spring.demo.model.Phone;

@Repository
public class PhoneDAOImpl implements Serializable, PhoneDAO {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PhoneDAOImpl.class);
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    @Override
    public void addPhone(Phone p) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(p);
        logger.info("Phone saved successfully, Phone Details=" + p);
    }

    @Override
    public void updatePhone(Phone p) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.update(p);
        logger.info("Phone updated successfully, Phone Details=" + p);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Phone> listPhones() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Phone> phonesList = session.createQuery("from Phone").list();
        for (Phone p : phonesList) {
            logger.info("Phone List::" + p);
        }
        return phonesList;
    }

    @Override
    public Phone getPhoneById(int id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Phone p = (Phone) session.load(Phone.class, new Integer(id));
        logger.info("Phone loaded successfully, Phone details=" + p);
        return p;
    }

    @Override
    public void removePhone(int id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Phone p = (Phone) session.load(Phone.class, new Integer(id));
        if (null != p) {
            session.delete(p);
        }
        logger.info("Phone deleted successfully, phone details=" + p);
    }
}
```

PhoneController :

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import fr.spring.demo.model.Phone;
import fr.spring.demo.service.PhoneService;

@Controller
public class PhoneController implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private PhoneService phoneService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "phoneService")
    public void setPhoneService(PhoneService ps) {
        this.phoneService = ps;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/phones", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPhones(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("phone", new Phone());
        model.addAttribute("listPhones", this.phoneService.listPhones());
        return "phone";
    }

    // For add and update phone both
    @RequestMapping(value = "/phone/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPhone(@ModelAttribute("phone") Phone p) {
        if (p.getId() == 0) {
            // new phone, add it
            this.phoneService.addPhone(p);
        } else {
            // existing phone, call update
            this.phoneService.updatePhone(p);
        }
        return "redirect:/phones";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
    public String removePhone(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        this.phoneService.removePhone(id);
        return "redirect:/phones";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String editPhone(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("phone", this.phoneService.getPhoneById(id));
        model.addAttribute("listPhones", this.phoneService.listPhones());
        return "phone";
    }
}
```

PostgreSQL log file :

```
2017-05-24 11:22:05 CEST ERREUR:  la colonne Â« procpid Â» n'existe pas au caractère 16
2017-05-24 11:22:05 CEST INSTRUCTION :  SELECT datname,procpid,current_query FROM pg_stat_activity;
2017-05-24 11:22:26 CEST ERREUR:  la colonne Â« procpid Â» n'existe pas au caractère 16
2017-05-24 11:22:26 CEST INSTRUCTION :  SELECT datname,procpid,current_query FROM pg_stat_activity;
2017-05-24 11:27:15 CEST ERREUR:  la relation Â« phone Â» n'existe pas au caractère 90
2017-05-24 11:27:15 CEST INSTRUCTION :  select phone0_.id as id1_0_, phone0_.name as name2_0_, phone0_.review as review3_0_ from PHONE phone0_
2017-05-24 11:55:20 CEST ERREUR:  la relation Â« phone Â» n'existe pas au caractère 90
2017-05-24 11:55:20 CEST INSTRUCTION :  select phone0_.id as id1_0_, phone0_.name as name2_0_, phone0_.review as review3_0_ from PHONE phone0_
2017-05-24 11:59:37 CEST ERREUR:  la relation Â« phone Â» n'existe pas au caractère 90
2017-05-24 11:59:37 CEST INSTRUCTION :  select phone0_.id as id1_0_, phone0_.name as name2_0_, phone0_.review as review3_0_ from PHONE phone0_
2017-05-24 11:59:42 CEST ERREUR:  la relation Â« phone Â» n'existe pas au caractère 90
2017-05-24 11:59:42 CEST INSTRUCTION :  select phone0_.id as id1_0_, phone0_.name as name2_0_, phone0_.review as review3_0_ from PHONE phone0_
2017-05-24 12:08:00 CEST ERREUR:  la relation Â« phone Â» n'existe pas au caractère 90
2017-05-24 12:08:00 CEST INSTRUCTION :  select phone0_.id as id1_0_, phone0_.name as name2_0_, phone0_.review as review3_0_ from PHONE phone0_
2017-05-24 12:16:10 CEST ERREUR:  la relation Â« phone Â» n'existe pas au caractère 90
2017-05-24 12:16:10 CEST INSTRUCTION :  select phone0_.id as id1_0_, phone0_.name as name2_0_, phone0_.review as review3_0_ from PHONE phone0_
```

AppServlet-servlet.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">

<context:component-scan
    base-package="fr.spring.demo.controller,fr.spring.demo.dao,fr.spring.demo.model,fr.spring.demo.service" />

<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers t o .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/soveco" />
    <property name="username" value="soveco" />
    <property name="password" value="soveco" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<bean id="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>
                fr.spring.demo.model.Phone
            </value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>     
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="phoneDAO" class="fr.spring.demo.dao.PhoneDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="phoneService" class="fr.spring.demo.service.PhoneServiceImpl">
    <property name="phoneDAO" ref="phoneDAO">
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory"
        ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"></bean>
```

pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SOVECO</groupId>
  <artifactId>SOVECO</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
    <primefaces.version>5.3</primefaces.version>
    <server.config>standalone.xml</server.config>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jsf.version>2.2.12</jsf.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.12</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.9</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.4.1212</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.21</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.21</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.21</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop` in your config. This will drop and recreate your database on everytime. If you have already created and then changed the hibernate Entities this would take care of that.